Create an empty 8x8 One Up puzzle with a unique solution
Rodolfo Kurchan created a wonderful new grid puzzle called One Up that you can play on his website. There is one main rule:
Each horizontal and vertical sequence of N cells between walls, must contain every number between 1 and N, in some order.
Can you construct an empty 8x8 One Up puzzle that has a single unique solution and it is connected - each empty cells can reach every other empty cell? No computers allowed.
Bonus: can you find a method for constructing such puzzles for any grid size?

Actually I found a solution to this question shortly after I posted this answer.
Puzzle:



Solution:



Solving path:

 Start from the lower right, filling the lower triangle by columns from the right and the upper triangle by rows from the bottom. The lower triangle is trivially filled, and the top 3 rows of the upper triangle can be filled in the reverse order from the rest.

This is an extension of the second "connected 3x3 One Up with unique solution" in my previous answer, and it works for any square size or a rectangle where one side is longer by 1 unit (remove the rightmost column).
For significantly rectangular grids, this construction seems to work:



Solving path:

 First look at the short columns crossing the bottom row. Fill them in just like a triangle. Then the longest columns are recursively fixed from bottom to top.

This should work for any grid size whose short side is at least 3 units.

Great solution! I particularly liked the generalization to non square grids.

I think this grid works:

 

It's not hard to see how all the entries are forced leading to a unique solution.

 First, the top right cell must be a 1, and the top row's 8 must go in the first column as the only one long enough for it. The grid is separated into the triangular regions, which each force a cascade from their bottom right corners, which have to be 1's.
 For an example of a step, say we've filled in this far:

 Now the marked cell is the only place to put a 1 in its row segment, which limits the 2 to the square to its right, then the 3 to its right, and finally the 4. The row above it is forced into ascending order by similar logic, and so on, up to the top row which works the same except the 1 is pre-placed on the right. The other triangle is similarly forced.

Final grid:

 

This generalizes to square grids of any size 3-by-3 and up (2-by-2 is impossible, and 1-by-1 is trivial).
